# Debugging OpenGL sample code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, opengl-es

Using a video tutorial, I tried to run some visual work using OpenGL with VS 12. I added all necessary files. Then I debug the code with VS 12.

Here is the code:

```
    // A Simple OpenGL Project
#include <glut.h>

void Draw() {


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
          glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
         glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);

          glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void Initialize() {

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

 int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {

    glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("XoaX.net");
    Initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

It shows the following problems:

1. The file is out of date
2. 

> Unable to start program 'c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\gameing try\debug\gaming try.exe' The system cannot find the file specified 
>   
>   No errors. What's wrong with it? How can I run it?

Comment: Does it have any compiler errors? In the 'Errors' window.

Comment: no error , totally nothing. its looks like error list part in now off.